# Why the hex value is different in python and Javascript (Node Js)

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I have been trying to encrypt something in Node JS and decrypt it in Python.

When I give the key(Secret key, base64 decoded) to Fernet.js, it forms a hex string which is equal to:

```
f790b0a226bc96a92de49b5e9c05e1ee
```

But when I give the same key in Python and try to convert into hex, the value is:

```
730ff4c7af3d46923e8ed451ee813c87f790b0a226bc96a92de49b5e9c05e1ee
```

Why there is a difference?

code sample for NodeJS:

```
let s = 'cw_0x689RpI-jtRR7oE8h_eQsKImvJapLeSbXpwF4e4='
new Buffer(s)).toString('hex')
```

Python:

```
be = base64.urlsafe_b64decode('cw_0x689RpI-jtRR7oE8h_eQsKImvJapLeSbXpwF4e4=')
be.hex()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import base64 , binascii

key = "cw_0x689RpI-jtRR7oE8h_eQsKImvJapLeSbXpwF4e4="
key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key)


# 32 bytes
f = binascii.hexlify(key)

# first 16 
SigningKey = key[:16]
# next 16 
EncKey = key[16:]


print (binascii.hexlify(SigningKey)) # 730ff4c7af3d46923e8ed451ee813c87
print (binascii.hexlify(EncKey)) # f790b0a226bc96a92de49b5e9c05e1ee
```

Comment: Thanks, Fernet library takes the second 16 bytes as you have done in your code.